# Uninstalling Lubuntu

Tags: uninstall

I have Win7 and Lubuntu installed as dual-boot, that was quite simple. But how to remove Lubuntu?...seems, at first glance, not so simple. 
How to do this without leftovers?

Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 0):

- Boot gparted live-disk or ubuntu live disk(if it was ubuntu live disk then install gparted partition editor).
- Delete the Lubuntu partition through gparted.
- After that ran [*boot-repair*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to repair your grub.